# One-word/phrase replacement for "made for the sake of being made"

Tags: american-english

Basically a phrase or a word replacement for something that was made just so it would exist, like a grouping being made for the sake of having a grouping".

I'm sorry I can't explain myself well but it's as if something was made just so it would exist for that purpose

Comment: The action (but not the artifact) is _perfunctory_. [[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfunctory)]: _perfunctory ...
1. done superficially, only as a matter of routine; careless or cursory_

Answer (score 2):

The only ones that spring to mind are "for no apparent reason" ([Collins: for no apparent reason](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/for-no-apparent-reason)) or "just because" ([Collins: just because](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/just-because))

For example:

```
For no apparent reason, an eccentric billionaire has opened a restaurant on the Moon.
```

or

```
The eccentric billionaire decided to open a restaurant on the Moon, just because.
```

Comment: Although the second one would probably make grammarians scream, I believe it is the more idiomatic way to impart this sentiment in a shorter form.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a word that literally means "made for the sake of being made", but on a more poetical level, the answer is:

> ART

Answer (score 0):

**for the sake of it** - if you do something for the sake of it, you do it because you want to and not for any particular reason ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/for-the-sake-of-it)).

Answer (score 0):

The group etc. is an [**end in itself**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/end-in-itself)
 from dictionary reference:

> A purpose or goal desired for its own sake (rather than to attain
>   something else). For example, For me, writing books is an end in
>   itself; they don't really make that much money. This expression
>   employs the noun end in the sense of “final cause or purpose,” a usage
>   dating from the early 1500s.